# ASP.NET MVC 5 an error occurs when calling the *.less in windows Azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, less, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a project in "ASP.NET MVC 5" and use "less" for files "bootstrap", use the following libraries:

http://www.nuget.org/packages/BundleTransformer.Core/
http://www.nuget.org/packages/BundleTransformer.Less/
http://www.nuget.org/packages/JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.Core/
http://www.nuget.org/packages/JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.Msie/
http://www.nuget.org/packages/MsieJavaScriptEngine/

in my BundleConfig.css I have this:

```
BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false;
bundles.UseCdn = true;
CssTransformer cssTransformer = new CssTransformer();
JsTransformer jsTransformer = new JsTransformer();
NullOrderer nullOrderer = new NullOrderer();

Bundle cssBundle = new CustomStyleBundle("~/bundles/css");
cssBundle.Include("~/Content/bootstrap/bootstrap.less");
cssBundle.Include("~/Content/font-awesome.css");
cssBundle.Include("~/Content/site.less");
cssBundle.Transforms.Add(cssTransformer);
cssBundle.Orderer = nullOrderer;
bundles.Add(cssBundle);
```

in my environment works fine and if I use IIS works fine, but when I make the publush in "Windows Azure" for "less" files get this error:

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Content-Length: 75
Content-Type: text/html
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Wed, 21 May 2014 11:56:01 GMT

The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.
```

Only with files less, others file like css o js return rigth

(I think I have another problem that does not display errors but that's another question). Web.config for error:

```
<system.web>

    <customErrors mode="Off">
    </customErrors>
```

**edit**

configuration for less in web.config like [this template](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/5ed81082-fc81-458a-a30c-0d15b6e8386f)

```
<bundleTransformer xmlns="http://tempuri.org/BundleTransformer.Configuration.xsd">

  <less>
    <jsEngine name="MsieJsEngine" />
  </less>

    <core>
        <css>
            <minifiers>
                <add name="NullMinifier" type="BundleTransformer.Core.Minifiers.NullMinifier, BundleTransformer.Core" />
            </minifiers>
            <translators>
                <add name="NullTranslator" type="BundleTransformer.Core.Translators.NullTranslator, BundleTransformer.Core" enabled="false" />
            <add name="LessTranslator" type="BundleTransformer.Less.Translators.LessTranslator, BundleTransformer.Less" /></translators>
        </css>
        <js>
            <minifiers>
                <add name="NullMinifier" type="BundleTransformer.Core.Minifiers.NullMinifier, BundleTransformer.Core" />
            </minifiers>
            <translators>
                <add name="NullTranslator" type="BundleTransformer.Core.Translators.NullTranslator, BundleTransformer.Core" enabled="false" />
            </translators>
        </js>

    </core>
</bundleTransformer>
<jsEngineSwitcher xmlns="http://tempuri.org/JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.Configuration.xsd">
  <core>
        <engines>
            <add name="MsieJsEngine" type="JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.Msie.MsieJsEngine, JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.Msie" />
        </engines>
    </core>
</jsEngineSwitcher>
```

Comment: What happens when you request the `.less` file directly (http://yourdomain.com/Content/site.less)?

Comment: This error "The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred." with all less file. I know it's little info, but I have no more right now

Comment: How does your `<dotless>` configuration section looks like in your `Web.config`?

Comment: I updated the question, and the same applies to with the template to upload to "windows azure"

Comment: Why did you set, `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations` to `false`?

Comment: BundleTransformer only works while *bundling*. In other words, the *.less files are never actually used by the client, but rather, transformed into CSS and then combined and minified before actually being sent down. Requesting the *.less file directly won't work unless IIS has a mime-type to handle it, but even setting that doesn't really help you, because again, IIS is not typically serving this file.

Comment: @ChrisPratt can you put this comment as an answer, because this is the solicion for my problem. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BundleTransformer only works while bundling. In other words, the *.less files are never actually used by the client, but rather, transformed into CSS and then combined and minified before actually being sent down. Requesting the *.less file directly won't work unless IIS has a mime-type to handle it, but even setting that doesn't really help you, because again, IIS is not typically serving this file.

Answer (score 3):

Remove from your code the following line:

```
cssBundle.Transforms.Add(cssTransformer);
```

This line is redundant and may cause errors when using the `CustomStyleBundle` class.